# Test if string is numeric

Tags: c, parsing, unit-testing, validation, fixed-point

I want to implement the following function:

```
// Return true if and only if 's' is numeric including
// leading positive/negative sign, decimal point.
bool isnumeric( const char * s );
```

It is somewhat similar to `strtol()` but I don't need to return the number.

My approach is to count various things unless I can bail out:

```
bool isnumeric( char const * str ) {
  if( !str ) { return false; }
  int signs = 0;
  int decimals = 0;
  int digits = 0;
  int digitsAfterDecimal = 0;

  for( char const * p = str; *p; ++p ) {

    if( (*p == '+') || (*p == '-') ) {
      if( (decimals > 0) || (digits > 0) ) { return false; }
      signs += 1;
      if( signs == 2 ) { return false; }
    }
    else if( *p == '.' ) {
      decimals += 1;
      if( decimals == 2 ) { return false; }
    }
    else if( ! isdigit( *p ) ) { 
      return false;
    }
    else {
      digits += 1;
      if( decimals > 0 ) {
        digitsAfterDecimal += 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return (decimals > 0) ? ((digits > 0) && (digitsAfterDecimal > 0))
                        : (digits > 0) ;
}
```

I also have the following tests:

```
void test_isnumeric() {
  assert( isnumeric( "42" ) );
  assert( isnumeric( "42.0" ) );
  assert( isnumeric( "42.56" ) );
  assert( isnumeric( "+42" ) );
  assert( isnumeric( ".42" ) );
  assert( isnumeric( "+.42" ) );

  assert( ! isnumeric( "42." ) );
  assert( ! isnumeric( "++42" ) );
  assert( ! isnumeric( "+." ) );
  assert( ! isnumeric( "4+" ) );
}

int main( void ) {
  test_isnumeric();
}
```

To make it easy to clone and modify, the full code is available [here](http://ideone.com/qotAhb).

Please comment on design, structuring, test coverage etc. Mentioning failing tests are most welcome.

Comment: Looks like you're using your `int`s mainly as `bool`s, might want to consider to use `bool`s there for that.

Comment: @Bobby: Which `int` variable you are referring to? The following `int` variables (`signs`, `decimals`, `digits`, `digitsAfterDecimal`) are used as counters.

Comment: Yes, but you're only testing them for greater than 0, that's basically what a boolean does. F.e. `decimals` might be `bool` called `hasDecimalPoint`, `*p == '.' ... if (hasDecimalPoint) return false; hasDecimalPoint = true;`.

Comment: @Bobby: Thanks for the followup comment and clarification, I *now* understand what you are saying. When I applied it, I could simplify the code. [Please feel free to enter your comment as an answer.] With counters, I retained more information as obtained from the scan than it is necessary for this particular problem, which might be helpful if the problem is modified.

Answer (score 4):

State variables are bad. Keep the state explicit, along the lines of:

```
if (*p == '+' || *p == '-') p++;
if (!isdigit(*p)) return False;
while (isdigit(*p)) p++;
if (*p == 0) return True;
if (*p != '.') return False;
p++;
while (isdigit(*p)) p++;
return *p == 0;
```

Update: few fixes thanks to [Edward](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/39848/edward)

Comment: +1; Thanks for reviewing my code. I would love to write a compact form such as yours. But, in that approach, I had difficulty covering the malformed inputs, for e.g. "42.", "+." etc. Perhaps I need to think harder :-)

Comment: @Arun I find it strange that you consider `42.` not to be a numeric value. In C, `42. == 42.0`.

Comment: I didn't mean the snippet to be working. In fact, it has certain problems in correctness (e.g. returning `True` for a suspicious "+.") and design. It is here only to demonstrate a stateless approach.

Comment: On line 4 you mean `(*p == 0)` rather than `(*p == '0')` to test for end of string rather than a zero digit and line 2 could be `if (!isdigit(*p)) return False;`

Comment: @Edward You are absolutely right. Fixing.

Answer (score 4):

Over-all no major problems - just nits.

1. Minor inefficiency.  Test for digits *first*.
2. A simple test for leading sign would do.
3. Decimal point is locale-sensitive.

   ```
   char dp = localeconv()->decimal_point[0].
   ```
4. Pedantic (meaning only the crazy care): When counting elements of an array, recommend type `size_t` rather than `int` for `digits`, `digitsAfterDecimal`.  Either that or fail if `digits` is to exceed `INT_MAX`.  The main issue here is security.   If a user can break your code by pasting in insane long string (when `INT_MAX < SIZE_MAX`) it represents a remote possibility.
5. Pedantic: The `bool` approach (@Bobby) will not overflow the digit count for insanely high number of digits like the present code.

---

Critique of coding goals - not code

1. Do not understand why the coding goal does not allow <strike>"123",</strike> "123."<strike>, ".123"</strike>.
2. `strtol()` will accept leading white-space.
3. Indicating the address of the fail location sounds like a useful enhancement.  E. g. return `p` on failure, `NULL` on success.

Comment: +1: Good Comments; Thank you. I like the pedantic (A.1) and strtol (B.2) and return NULL (B.3). On B.1, "123" and ".123" are expected to be accepted, only "123." is not.

Comment: Corrected.  My mis-read of the program flow, though my mistake, was mis-inteprettting `decimals > 0) ? ((digits > 0) && (digitsAfterDecimal > 0)) : (digits > 0)`.  I like @Bobby idea to use boolean when only 2 states matter.  OTOH the end may be `decimals ? (digits && digitsAfterDecimal) : digits;` or even `(decimals && digitsAfterDecimal) || digits`.  OT3H, if "123." was OK, then `return digits`.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Suggest: To test cases add those pesky empty cases of `assert( ! isnumeric( "" ) );`, `assert( ! isnumeric(NULL) );`