# Test if a string is a number

Tags: c, strings, validation, i18n

In need for testing if a string is a number which could be a double or integer, I wrote a simple skeleton, which parses a string like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

char* to_convert = argv[1];
char* p = NULL;
errno = 0;
long val = strtol(argv[1], &p, 0);

if (errno != 0)
return 1;// conversion failed (EINVAL, ERANGE)

if (to_convert == p){
// conversion to int failed (no characters consumed)
double val2 = strtod(p, &p);
if (*p){
printf("Not a number!\n");
return 1;
}
printf("Double %lf\n" , val2);
return 0;
}

if (*p != 0){
// conversion to int failed (trailing data)
double val2 = strtod(argv[1], &p);
if (*p){
printf("Not a number!\n");
return 1;
}
printf("Double %lf\n" , val2);
return 0;
}

printf("Int %ld\n" , val);
return 0;
}

/*
$ ./a.out 123
Int 123
$ ./a.out -123
Int -123
$ ./a.out 31.1
Double 31.100000
$ ./a.out -231
Int -231
$ ./a.out NaN
Double nan
$ ./a.out -Nan
Double nan
$ ./a.out -INF
Double -inf
$ ./a.out INF
Double inf
$ ./a.out 12.3
Double 12.300000
$ ./a.out -12,3  # Although some european localels (like German, would consider this a number)
Not a number!
$ ./a.out -12.3
Double -12.300000
$ ./a.out foo
Not a number!
*/
```

I would like to know if this could be done better, without iterating on all the characters [like here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/48438/test-string-if-numeric).

1. Is there any case I didn't think of which breaks this code?
2. or causes undefined behaviour (except numbers larger than long on my architechture)?

Another thing is the problem with decimal seperator. How do you convert a number where the decimal separator is comma instead of a point like in the German language? This would be a nice to have, but not a must.

For example, my code says `12,3` is not a number, for a German person this would be a number (`12.3` for English speakers).

Comment: Internationalization is a broad topic with many pitfalls. Is 十二 a number? Is 12,345 to be interpreted as (12 + 345/1000) or as (12 * 1000 + 345)? A [fully general solution](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/unum_8h.html) is very complex.

Comment: You can achieve this solution by suing `if (sscanf(data, "%*lf%n", &count) == 1 && data[count] == '\0') { /* Its a Number */ }`. Also scanf is uses the local local for number scanning. ;

Comment: @LokiAstari, does your suggestion differentiate between float and integer? Can you explain what do "%*lf%n" means?

Comment: @Oz123: The bit in the comment does not. But it is easy to expand the above code so that you can detect integers or floating point numbers (in a local aware way). "%lf" is a `long float` ie a double. "%*lf" is the same but the star means don't store. "%n" means count the number of characters that have been read from the input.

Comment: OK, thank you. I like how compact C can sometimes be, but for readability, it can be really confusing sometimes.

Comment: @LokiAstari Using `if (sscanf(data, "%*lf %n", &count) == 1 && data[count] == '\0')` (note added space) has the advantage of allowing leading white-space (due to `"%lf"`), _and_ also allowing trailing white-space.

Answer (score 1):

`int` test and `double` test are incompletely done.

```
errno = 0;
long val = strtol(argv[1], &p, 0);
if (errno) Fail();         // Range error (or possible other reasons)
if (argv[1] == p) Fail();  // no conversion
while (isspace((unsigned char) *p)) p++;
if (*p) Fail();            // Extra junk afterwards
```

`if (*p) Fail();` Needs to be applied to both integer and FP test.

`while (isspace((unsigned char) *p)) p++;` allows trailing white-space.  Both `strtol()` and `strtod()` allow leading white-space.

Double is more complex as in the case of underflow like "1e-10000", the `errno` *may* set and that is usually *not* considered an error in many uses.  The returned value will be either +/-0.0 or a small `double` value.

```
double val2 = strtod(argv[1], &p);
if (errno == ERANGE && fabs(val2) <= DBL_MIN) NoFail();
```

Keep in mind a string may nicely translate to a `long` as well as a `double`.  Should "-0" be a`long 0` or `double -0.0`?  Aside from this case, I would favor `long`, especially if the test for extra junk is used.

Your test cases do not include big values "123...thousand_more...456", values like LONG_MIN (-1, +0, +1) and  LONG_MAX (-1, +0, +1), DBL_MAX, next_after(DBL_MAX,0), strings with trailing garbage "123xyz", -0.0.  BTW: a harsh check it to use `(char) -1` in various places in the string. Or lead the string with `(char) (x80 + ' ')`

Nor does it test odd things like "++123", "0x0xABC", "08".  (multiple sign, 2-prefix, octal 8) and new emerging "0b0101"  (C14?)

Extreme FP strings include "0.000...0001e320", "" and "  " (white-space only strings.)

FP also has a hexadecimal format, see `scanf("%a")/printf("%a")` for additional strings.

Original request was for "double or integer".  Code conveniently uses `long`, but what if `int` was meant or `intmax_t`?  Example additional test for `int`

```
long val = strtol(argv[1], &p, 0);
if (val < INT_MIN || val > INT_MAX) RangeError();
int i = (int) val;
...
```

To cope with decimal separator as `,` or `.`, use `setlocale()` and that will adjust `strtol()` and `strtod()`.  But that is a weak aspect of C.

Lastly, a given locale could have "additional subject sequences" that convert into numbers.